# insert xml node without XmlDomument.Load() in c#+XML

Tags: c#, xml

Have an log.xml file with nodes

```
<AppXmlLogWritter>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201302071614556349583069537201151138</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130207161455</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>BaburaoLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>BaburaoLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>BaburaoLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>BaburaoLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>BaburaoLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
  <LogData>
    <LogID>5678201302071614556349583069537201151138</LogID>
    <LogDateTime>20130207161455</LogDateTime>
    <LogType>Warning</LogType>
    <LogFlag>BaburaoLogFlag</LogFlag>
    <LogApplication>BaburaoLogApplication</LogApplication>
    <LogModule>BaburaoLogModule</LogModule>
    <LogLocation>BaburaoLogLocation</LogLocation>
    <LogText>BaburaoLogText</LogText>
  </LogData>
</AppXmlLogWritter>
```

I want to add some few new node by replacing the Root Node `<AppXmlLogWritter>` in XML file. without overwriting older node. but my code replace the old node by my new node I want to preserve that old node with new node

```
Mutex objMutex = new Mutex(false, @"Global\MySharedLog");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            string currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            XmlElement newelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogData");
            XmlElement xmlLogID = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogID");
            XmlElement xmlLogDateTime = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogDateTime");
            XmlElement xmlLogType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogType");
            XmlElement xmlLogFlag = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogFlag");
            XmlElement xmlLogApplication = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogApplication");
            XmlElement xmlLogModule = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogModule");
            XmlElement xmlLogLocation = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogLocation");
            XmlElement xmlLogText = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogText");
            XmlElement xmlLogStackTrace = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LogStackTrace");

            int randomNumber = random.Next(9999);
            xmlLogID.InnerText = _logIDPrefix + currentDateTime + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks + randomNumber;
            xmlLogDateTime.InnerText = currentDateTime;
            xmlLogType.InnerText = ((LogTypes)Convert.ToInt32(logType)).ToString();
            xmlLogFlag.InnerText = logFlag;
            xmlLogApplication.InnerText = _logApplication;
            xmlLogModule.InnerText = logModule;
            xmlLogLocation.InnerText = logLocation;
            xmlLogText.InnerText = logText;
            xmlLogStackTrace.InnerText = logStackTrace;

            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogID);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogDateTime);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogType);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogFlag);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogApplication);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogModule);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogLocation);
            newelement.AppendChild(xmlLogText);

            try
            {
                objMutex.WaitOne();
                if (!File.Exists(_logFilePath))
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(_logFilePath, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16' standalone='yes'?>\n<AppXmlLogWritter>\n</AppXmlLogWritter>");
                }
                string fileContains = string.Empty;
                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(_logFilePath))
                {
                    if (line.Contains("<AppXmlLogWritter>"))
                    {
                        fileContains = line.Replace("<AppXmlLogWritter>", "<AppXmlLogWritter>" + newelement.OuterXml.ToString());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                //xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;                
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(fileContains);
                // //xmlDoc.Load(_logFilePath);
                XmlElement ele = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newelement);
                xmlDoc.Save(_logFilePath);
            }
            finally
            {
                objMutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
```

ie both the old node and new node are save to a file without replacing the old node.

Comment: Can you give example of the resulting xml, your explanation doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the issue now become much more faster than load method of XmlDocument code is i just replace the try block which is correctly work and remainind code as it is

```
            string rootEndTag = "</AppXmlLogWritter>";
            int rootEndTagLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rootEndTag).Length;
            try
            {
                objMutex.WaitOne();
                if (!File.Exists(_logFilePath))
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(_logFilePath, "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?><AppXmlLogWritter></AppXmlLogWritter>");
                }

                var fileStream = File.Open(_logFilePath, FileMode.Open);
                fileStream.Position = fileStream.Length - rootEndTagLength;

                var objStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                objStreamWriter.WriteLine(newelement.OuterXml);
                objStreamWriter.Write(rootEndTag);
                objStreamWriter.Close();
                fileStream.Close();
            }
```